# Triangle function.

Tags: real-analysis

We define

$\phi(x)=|x|$

if $-1\leq x \leq 1$ and $\phi(x+2)=\phi(x)$ for all the other $x\in \mathbb{R}$. For a fixed integer $m$ we define $\delta_m=\frac{1}{2}4^{-m}$ and
$\gamma_n=\displaystyle\frac{\phi( 4^{n}(x+\delta_m))-\phi (4^nx)}{\delta_m}$.

Why $|\gamma_m|=4^{m}$?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's explore some examples to see what is $f(x)=\phi(x+1/2)-\phi(x)$.

- For $0\leq x\leq1/2$ it is $1/2$.
- For $1/2\leq x\leq 1$, $\phi(x)=x$, but $\phi(x+1/2)=3/2-x$, and $f(x)=3/2-2x$.
- For $1\leq x\leq3/2$, $f(x)=-1/2$
- Last, for $3/2\leq x\leq 2$, $f(x)=2x-3/2$.

The only thing that we can guarantee is that $|f(x)|\leq1/2$. Then

$$|\gamma_n|=2^{2m+1}\left|\phi\left(4^mx+\frac12\right)-\phi(4^mx)\right|=2^{2m+1}|f(4^mx)|\leq 4^m$$